# Replace \n with <br> and \r\n with <p> in javascript

Tags: javascript, string

I need JS that will remove any HTML tags, and then replace newlines with `</p><p>` and line breaks with `<br/>`. The string value is coming from a textarea and I understand Linux, Mac and Windows all format newlines differently so I need to take that into account. Thanks!

Comment: So you want the replace to be different depending on the line endings? Also, `\n` and `\r\n` can both be called newlines or line breaks. I think a use case might be beneficial here.

Answer (score 24):

\n and \r\n are equivalent. Linux uses the former, Windows uses the latter.

What you want to do is replace all cases of \n\n and \r\n\r\n with `<p></p>` and case of simply \n or \r\n with `<br />`

```
result = "<p>" + text + "</p>";
result = result.replace(/\r\n\r\n/g, "</p><p>").replace(/\n\n/g, "</p><p>");
result = result.replace(/\r\n/g, "<br />").replace(/\n/g, "<br />");
```

This assumes there is no html in your text.

Answer (score 1):

I think

```
value.replace(/\\n\\n/g, "</p><p>");
value.replace(/\\n/g, "<br/>");
```

will do the trick.